# Why is this CASE GREATEST returning NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, mariadb, case

I have a select query that looks like this, so that I know which date is the newest (dtStart) and which table the newest date comes from (TableOrigin).

```
WITH ranked_entity AS (
 SELECT
    table5.id,
    GREATEST(
        COALESCE(table1.dtEvaluationStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), 
        COALESCE(table2.dtStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), 
        COALESCE(table3.dtEvaluationStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
        COALESCE(table4.dtStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00')) as dtStart,
    CASE GREATEST(
        COALESCE(table1.dtEvaluationStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), 
        COALESCE(table2.dtStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), 
        COALESCE(table3.dtEvaluationStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
        COALESCE(table4.dtStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
        )
    WHEN table1.dtEvaluationStart THEN 'table1'
    WHEN table2.dtStart THEN 'table2'
    WHEN table3.dtEvaluationStart THEN 'table3'
    WHEN table4.dtStart THEN 'table4'
    END AS TableOrigin,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dtStart DESC) AS rn
 FROM table5 
    LEFT JOIN table1 ON table5.id = table1.fid 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table5.id = table2.fid
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON table5.id = table3.fid 
    LEFT JOIN table4 ON table5.id = table4.fid
)
    SELECT * FROM ranked_entity WHERE rn = 1;
```

But sometimes the TableOrigin is NULL even though dtStart is set. Why is that so?

For example in one row the column dtStart has the value '2020-05-14 14:34:18' that is taken from table3, because it is the newest date out of the columns of the four tables. That means that the column TableOrigin should have the value 'table3' for this row. But instead TableOrigin is NULL.
This doesn't happen with all the rows, in some rows the TableOrigin value is correct.

Sample Data:

```
table5
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 198 |
| 197 |
+-----+

table1
+-----+---------------------+
| fid |  dtEvaluationStart  |
+-----+---------------------+
| 198 | 2018-01-11 13:59:17 |
| 197 | 2020-01-21 09:29:35 |
+-----+---------------------+

table2
+-----+---------------------+
| fid |       dtStart       |
+-----+---------------------+
| 198 | 2018-02-01 12:57:50 |
| 197 | 2020-11-18 10:14:31 |
+-----+---------------------+

table3
+-----+---------------------+
| fid |       dtStart       |
+-----+---------------------+
| 197 | 2018-01-10 14:58:19 |
+-----+---------------------+

table4
+-----+---------------------+
| fid |       dtStart       |
+-----+---------------------+
| 198 | 2020-03-01 09:40:09 |
| 197 | 2020-03-04 08:10:59 |
+-----+---------------------+

output
+-----+---------------------+-------------+
| id  |       dtStart       | TableOrigin |
+-----+---------------------+-------------+
| 198 | 2020-03-01 09:40:09 | NULL        |
| 197 | 2020-11-18 10:14:31 | table2      |
+-----+---------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Is there a case that all 4 columns table1.dtEvaluationStart, table2.dtStart, table3.dtEvaluationStart, table4.dtStart may be null in the same row?

Comment: Yes, in my case only in two rows. In this two rows dtStart is then '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. But TableOrigin is also in other rows NULL.

Comment: You have to post sample data so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: I've edited the post and added the sample data.

Comment: You forgot Table3.

Comment: I've added table3 even though, it isn't needed since not every id from table5 has a fid in every other tables. For example table3 doesn't have a fid 198. And I don't think this is the problem because there are other cases where the id from table5 doesn't have a fid every other tables, but TableOrigin has the correct value.

Comment: The code works fine and does not return nulls: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3018d3d86763fbd9c190bfc250afb89e

Comment: I've updated the mysql code and now the issue is reproducible. I've left this part of code out, because honestly I didn't think that was the problem.

Comment: Works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d1084f7e8d02ee96a69a46e4085802a4

Comment: I have a MariaDB database, and there it doesn't work. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d1084f7e8d02ee96a69a46e4085802a4

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the code works fine in MySql, it does not work in MariaDB. 
As a workaround you can repeat `COALESCE()` in your `CASE` expression:

```
WITH ranked_entity AS (
 SELECT
    table5.id,
    GREATEST(
        COALESCE(table1.dtEvaluationStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), 
        COALESCE(table2.dtStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), 
        COALESCE(table3.dtEvaluationStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
        COALESCE(table4.dtStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00')) as dtStart,
    CASE GREATEST(
        COALESCE(table1.dtEvaluationStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), 
        COALESCE(table2.dtStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), 
        COALESCE(table3.dtEvaluationStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
        COALESCE(table4.dtStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
        )
    WHEN COALESCE(table1.dtEvaluationStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00') THEN 'table1'
    WHEN COALESCE(table2.dtStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00') THEN 'table2'
    WHEN COALESCE(table3.dtEvaluationStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00') THEN 'table3'
    WHEN COALESCE(table4.dtStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00') THEN 'table4'
    END AS TableOrigin,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table5.id ORDER BY table4.dtStart DESC) AS rn
 FROM table5 
    LEFT JOIN table1 ON table5.id = table1.fid 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table5.id = table2.fid
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON table5.id = table3.fid 
    LEFT JOIN table4 ON table5.id = table4.fid
)
SELECT * FROM ranked_entity WHERE rn = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=cffca2f5bcc038b9ceff28479d823c5e).
Results:

```
>  id | dtStart             | TableOrigin | rn
> --: | :------------------ | :---------- | -:
> 197 | 2020-11-18 10:14:31 | table2      |  1
> 198 | 2020-03-01 09:40:09 | table4      |  1
```

Answer (score 1):

`dstart` is always going to be set.  However, if the value is `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`, then all the compared values are (presumably) `NULL`.  The constant value doesn't match `NULL` so the column name is not matched.

The `NULL` value is expressing this.

If you also want `dtstart` to be `NULL` in this case, then use `NULLIF()`:

```
NULLIF(GREATEST(COALESCE(table1.dtEvaluationStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), 
                COALESCE(table2.dtStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), 
                COALESCE(table3.dtEvaluationStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
                COALESCE(table4.dtStart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
               ), '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
      )
```